# how to Inject dependency in static method with spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, static-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make spring inject value into a static field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324372/how-to-make-spring-inject-value-into-a-static-field)

I have below code

```
public class CustomerService {

  private static CustomerDAO customerDao;

  public static void getAllCustomers()
  {
    customerDao.getAllCustomers();// here i want 
  }

      public static CustomerDAO getCustomerDao() {
    return customerDao;
  }

  public static void setCustomerDao(CustomerDAO customerDao) {
    CustomerService.customerDao = customerDao;
  }
}
```

now i am calling CustomerService.getAllCustomers() from my  Action object  where getAllCustomers
is class level method. I want customerDao to be injected by spring in class CustomerService
so that when i call getAllCustomers dependency is available ?

I am using spring decalarative dependency injection

Comment: Why must the DAO be static?  It's a simple thing if it's not.  I don't see the reason for making it a class variable.

Comment: There are a lot of equal questions at stack overflow: search for `[Spring] inject static`!

Comment: Having everything static seems a little odd. Do you have a good reason for this?

Answer (score 3):

Your design collides head-on with the basic premise of Spring IoC. A `static` method is nothing more than a singleton method, and the core point of the IoC container is to manage your singletons. You must redesign to use instance methods and fields.

The only way `static` methods get into the picture is as factory methods, when some complex logic is needed to contribute a singleton to the container.

Answer (score 0):

Do not declare the customerDao field `static`. Then wire the customer dao into your service class like:

```
<bean id="customerDao" class="com.example.CustomerDao">
    <!-- whatever config you may need here -->
</bean>

<bean id="customerService" class="com.example.CustomerSerivce">
    <property name="" ref="customerDao"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: cannot make a static reference to a non-static field !