# Assign data member of a domain class using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible?

Here is a more detailed case:

```
class A {
    private service x;

    //other members
    //some more methods.
}
```

bean definition is available for `service` but I do not want `class A` to be a spring bean and neither x to be static.

Is this achievable.

EDIT:

My spring configuration:

```
<bean id="Service" class="com.xx.yy.Service" />
<--!I do not register class A as a bean. Hence cannot use @autowired directly.-->
```

Comment: Do you wanr service in class A to be managed by spring?

Comment: @DarshanLila yes. but not the whole class. I have a bean for the service but I just want to initialize the data member in this class.

Comment: If you don't tell spring that your class A is a bean (using annotation or XML), spring won't manage them.

Comment: @Athanor I am not asking spring to manage them. I just need a way to assign a data member which is managed by spring.

Comment: Check out @Autowired with component scan

Comment: @DarshanLila Hope you are talking about this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan. This needs the bean to be regiested with @Compoment, if I am not wrong. I do not want to register `class A` as a bean.

Comment: @Athanor I have edited the question with more details. Here is a very similar question but the members are that need to be assigned are static:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324372/how-to-make-spring-inject-value-into-a-static-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can only be achieved by manually getting the bean from the context.

```
Service service = context.getBean(Service.class);
A a = new A(service);
```

Comment: is something close to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324372/how-to-make-spring-inject-value-into-a-static-field not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create the factory for instances of class A which should take care of setting x.

```
@Service
class FactoryA {

  @Autowired service x;

  public A create() {
    return new A(x);
  }

}
```

Comment: But does it even qualify for factory pattern? I do not a decision to be made at run time.

Comment: Of course it does. Take a look on Building blocks of DDD :)