# How to inject static variables from spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, static-members

How to inject static variables from spring bean?

```
public class MyClass{
    static String str;
    // how to set value to this variable through Spring
}

<b>Spring bean</b>
<bean id='myclass' class = 'com.so.MyClass'>
    <property name="str" value="xmlpath" />
</bean>.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make spring inject value into a static field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324372/how-to-make-spring-inject-value-into-a-static-field)

Comment: This is possible but usually indicates a design problem.

Comment: Don't use statics at all. It makes your code incredibly difficult to test properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a none static setter for your static variable

```
public void setStr(String str) {
    your.package.MyClass.str = str;
}
```

and in your context :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="yourMethod" value="your.packaged.MyClass.setStr"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <ref bean="str"/>
        </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

In property tag property name would be "staticMethod" according to me