# How to inject bean in a Tapestry service

Tags: spring, tapestry, tynamo

I want to inject bean in a Tapestry service (not in a page).

For the moment, I use this :

```
public class EntityRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/application-context-security.xml");
SecurityServices securityServices = (SecurityServices)ctx.getBean("securityServices");
```

It works, but I want use this :

```
public class EntityRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

@Inject
private SecurityServices securityServices;
```

And my applicationContext is in the web.xml.
In this second case, the injection doesn't work. Why ?

AppModule.java :

```
public class AppModule
{

//@Resource(name = "realm")
@Inject
private static EntityRealm realm;

@Contribute(WebSecurityManager.class)
public static void addRealms(Configuration<EntityRealm> configuration) {

    //EntityRealm realm = new EntityRealm();

    configuration.add(realm);
}

public static void contributeFactoryDefaults( MappedConfiguration<String, Object> configuration)
{
    configuration.override(SecuritySymbols.LOGIN_URL, "/login");
    configuration.override(SecuritySymbols.UNAUTHORIZED_URL, "/login");
    configuration.override(SecuritySymbols.SUCCESS_URL, "/index");
    configuration.override(SymbolConstants.APPLICATION_VERSION, "2.0-SNAPSHOT");
}

public static void contributeApplicationDefaults(MappedConfiguration<String, Object> configuration)
{
    configuration.add(SymbolConstants.HMAC_PASSPHRASE, new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32));
    configuration.add(SymbolConstants.SUPPORTED_LOCALES, "en,fr");
    configuration.add( "tapestry.default-cookie-max-age", "31536000" ); 
}

public RequestFilter buildTimingFilter(final Logger log)
{
    return new RequestFilter()
    {
        public boolean service(Request request, Response response, RequestHandler handler)
                throws IOException
        {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try
            {
                return handler.service(request, response);
            } finally
            {
                long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                log.info(String.format("Request time: %d ms", elapsed));
            }
        }
    };
}

public void contributeRequestHandler(OrderedConfiguration<RequestFilter> configuration,
                                     @Local
                                     RequestFilter filter)
{
    configuration.add("Timing", filter);
}
}
```

And the EntityRealm.java :

public class EntityRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

```
//***************************************
//************* Attributes  *************
//***************************************   
//ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/application-context-security.xml");

//SecurityServices securityServices = (SecurityServices)ctx.getBean("securityServices");

//@Resource(name = "securityServices")
@Inject
private SecurityServices securityServices;

//***************************************
//************ Constructors *************
//***************************************

public EntityRealm() {
    super(new MemoryConstrainedCacheManager());
    setName("myapprealm");
    setAuthenticationTokenClass(UsernamePasswordToken.class);

} 

//***************************************
//********** Public Methods *************
//***************************************
@Override
protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    if (principals == null) throw new AuthorizationException("PrincipalCollection was null, which should not happen");
```

application-context.xml :

```
<bean id="realm" class="net.atos.m2m.telecom.ihm.services.EntityRealm">
    <property name="securityServices" ref="securityServices"></property>
</bean> 

<bean id="securityServices" class="net.atos.m2m.telecom.ihm.applicatif.services.security.impl.SecurityServicesImpl">
    <property name="servicesTelSecu" ref="servicesTelSecu"></property>
    <property name="converterSecDSPtoDTO" ref="converterSecDSPtoDTO"></property>
    <property name="converterSecDTOtoDSP" ref="converterSecDTOtoDSP"></property>
</bean>
```

Can you help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How i say in previous comment, if you create EntityRealm in this way .. new EntityRealm() the inject\autowire does not work.

You must define EntityRealm as bean .. XML or Annotation.

```
<bean id="entityRealm" class="package.EntityRealm"/>
<bean id="securityServices" class="package.SecurityServices"/>
```

Comment: I have these two beans in my app context file. In my appModule, I inject the entityRealm (see in my first message). When I run the app, I have an exception (Service contribution (to service 'WebSecurityManager') was null). So "realm" is not injected.

Comment: In the other revision of your answear there is EntityRealm realm = new EntityRealm(); and when you create in this way an object, all annotations don't work. what is name of EntityRealm bean? "realm"? if not you should add @Qualifier("realm")

Comment: Yes, the name is realm. `@Inject
 @Qualifier("realm")
 private static EntityRealm realm;` Always the same, no injection.

Comment: You shouldn't use a static field.. in this case follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11324464/3364187)

Comment: Is a pleasure to help you :) tell us if you solve the problem :)

Comment: I added in app context :  `<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
     <property name="staticMethod" value="net.atos.m2m.telecom.ihm.services.AppModule.setEntityRealm"/>
     <property name="arguments">
         <list>
             <ref bean="entityRealm"/>
         </list>
    </property>
 </bean> `

Comment: And in AppModule.java : 
 
 `@Inject
 @Qualifier("realm")
 private static EntityRealm realm;
 
 public static void setRealm(EntityRealm er) {
  realm = er;
 }
  
    @Contribute(WebSecurityManager.class)
    public static void addRealms(Configuration<EntityRealm> configuration) {
     
     //EntityRealm realm = new EntityRealm();
     
     configuration.add(realm);
    } ` 
 
 I obtain an error : AppModule contains unrecognized public methods (setEntityRealm)...

Comment: change this public static void setRealm(EntityRealm er) in public static void setEntityRealm(EntityRealm er)

Comment: I changed realm by entityRealm everywhere (in app context and AppModule.java). `@Inject
 @Qualifier("entityRealm")
 private static EntityRealm entityRealm;
 
 public static void setEntityRealm(EntityRealm er) {
  entityRealm = er;
 }`        Error is the same : Module class net.atos.m2m.telecom.ihm.services.AppModule contains unrecognized public methods: public static void net.atos.m2m.telecom.ihm.services.AppModule.setEntityRealm(net.atos.m2m.telecom.ihm.services.EntityRealm).

Comment: If this way don't work, you use a simple set property by xml and set the static field... are you sure that do you want use a static field? .. isn't best practices.

Comment: No, i don't want to use static field, but if the field is not static, I have an error here : `@Contribute(WebSecurityManager.class)
    public static void addRealms(Configuration<EntityRealm> configuration) {
     //EntityRealm entityRealm = new EntityRealm();
     configuration.add(entityRealm);
    }`  "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field entityRealm"

Comment: I'm stupid... I removed static here : 'public void addRealms' and it's OK. Thank you very much Xstian. (I wonder why this method is static in the Tynamo documentation..)

Comment: :D is a pleasure, i suggest you to close this issue because the discussion is very long :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Resource` instead,

```
@Resource(name = "securityServices")
private SecurityServices securityServices;
```

And make sure that *application-context-security.xml* file is loaded by Spring.

Comment: Than you. With the annotation @Resource, I can't add ("securityServices"). And how verify that the application-context is loaded by Spring ?

Comment: You should add a variable `name`: `@Resource(name = "securityServices")`.

Comment: To verify application-context is loaded, you can check the log information of loading XMLs by Spring when the app is starting.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it, it doesn't work. The result is the same that @Inject : no injection

Comment: The application-context file is loaded : Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context-mock.xml]

Comment: how do you retrieve this object EntityRealm ? if you perform a new EntityRealm() the @Inject does not work.

Comment: @user2007861, where is your `SecurityServices` service defined?. If it is defined in a xml file, make sure the file is loaded.

Comment: Yes, the xml file (with securityServices) is loaded. The object EntityRealm is created with a new EntityRealm() in the class AppModule.