# Invoke static method from spring config

Tags: java, xml, spring, static

Is it possible to invoke static method in Spring configuration file?

```java
public MyClass {

   public static void staticMethod() {
       //do something
   }

}
```

```xml
<bean id="myBean" class="MyClass">
   <!-- invoke here -->
</bean>
```

Comment: What does staticMethod do? init the bean?

Comment: In order for spring to invoke it automatically it must belong to some spring bean. There is no meaning to just calling it from the configuration.

Comment: The static method initializes instance of myClass

Comment: I need to return a value from a static method and use the value as property value
<property name="" value=""/>, can any one help please

Comment: Use `@Value` annotation as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60556247/839733

Answer (score 23):

1. When the static method creates an instance of MyClass you an do it like this

*config*

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyClass" factory-method="staticMethod">
   <!-- invoke here -->
</bean>
```

*code*

```
public static MyClass staticMethod() {
       //create and Configure a new Instance
}
```

2. If you want the method only to be called on bean instantiation spring can't do it this way.

*config*

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyClass" init-method="init">
   <!-- invoke here -->
</bean>
```

*code*

```
public static void staticMethod() {
       //create and Configure a new Instance
}

public void init() {
     staticMethod();
}
```

Comment: Don't know why this answer was down-voted... it answers the question more accurately than the up-voted answer IMO.

Comment: I need to return a value from a static method and use the value as property value <property name="" value=""/>, can any one help please

Comment: What if the static method requires arguments? how do you pass them?

Comment: Method 1 won't work with params this way.  With method 2 the params could be instance properties of MyClass and used int init() as args to staticMethod. more examples here https://www.javatpoint.com/dependency-injection-with-factory-method . May type 3 from the examples could help.

Answer (score 17):

try this

```
<bean id="b1" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="MyClass.staticMethod" />
</bean>
```

see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingBean.html

Comment: MethodInvokingFactoryBean also assumes the method has a return value.

Comment: Is there a way to return a static value?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
<!-- call static method -->
<bean id="test" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="MyClass" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="staticMethod" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>anArgument</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Remove arguments as you might not need them.

Taken from https://gist.github.com/bulain/1139874

I was needing to call a static method. The above code worked fine.

This might be useful as well: [How to make spring inject value into a static field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324372/how-to-make-spring-inject-value-into-a-static-field).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using annotations for spring configuration you can add the following method into your @Configuration class:

```
@Bean
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean() {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setStaticMethod("MyClass.staticMethod");

    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
}
```