# Make spring @Value take default value from static field

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I have a java configuration where I create bean using some properties, defined in `application.properties`. For one of them I have a default value which is pretty long, so I extracted this value to a `public static final String` field of this configuration, now I want to make `@Value` use it as a default value.

So eventually I want something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    public static final String DEFAULT_PROPERTY_VALUE = "long string...";

    @Bean("midPriceDDSEndpoint")
    public DistributedDataSpace<Long, MidPriceStrategy> midPriceDDSEndpoint(
        @Value("${foo.bar.my-property:DEFAULT_PROPERTY_VALUE}") String myPropertyValue) {
    ... create and return bean...
    }
}
```

However by spring doesn't my field, so I am curious if I can somehow make it lookup it.

One way to fix this, is to access this static field through the configuration bean: `@Value(${foo.bar.my-property:#{myConfigurationBeanName.DEFAULT_PROPERTY_VALUE}})`, but using this approach makes constructor unreadable, because `Value` annotation then takes a lot of space(as property name and configuration bean name is longer then in this example). Is there any other way to make spring use static field as a default value for property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may just want to inject `Environment`, and get the value as default like so:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    public static final String DEFAULT_PROPERTY_VALUE = "long string...";

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean("midPriceDDSEndpoint")
    public DistributedDataSpace<Long, MidPriceStrategy> midPriceDDSEndpoint() {
        String myPropertyValue = env.getProperty("foo.bar.my-property", DEFAULT_PROPERTY_VALUE);
    }
}
```

I personally think that's a little bit more readable...

Comment: Not a direct answer to what the OP asked for, which is using `@Value`.

Answer (score 8):

I would do 
    `@Value("${foo.bar.my-property:" + DEFAULT_PROPERTY_VALUE + "}")`

Comment: thats a good idea, I thought about that, but are there any forbidden symbols in such case? I mean this defualt value is not alphanumerical and contains such symbols as `{}=,.` etc., would such declaration properly work with that?

Comment: No difference as settings the default value directly in @Value,  the constant don't change anything

Comment: Only works with publicly accessible static constants. See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

@Vyncent's answer is limited in scope because it only works with publicly accessible static constants, since annotation attributes must be compile-time constants. To invoke a static method, use the following:

```
@Value("${demo.parallelism:#{T(java.lang.Runtime).getRuntime().availableProcessors()}}")
private int parallelism;
```

This sets `parallelism` = `demo.parallelism` JVM variable or gets the number of processors dynamically.

Comment: This pattern also works nicely for constants, e.g. @Value("${foo.bar.my-property:#{T(fully.qualified.package.MyConfiguration).DEFAULT_PROPERTY_VALUE}}")

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's not possible. The real question here is why you would need to do something like that? What is the use case? You can always make a simple workaround like

```
private String getMyPropertyValue() {
    return myPropertyValue.equals("some_explicitly_defined_default_value") ? DEFAULT_PROPERTY_VALUE : myPropertyValue;
}
```

Comment: I am not really sure what does your code do. Why its comparing propertyValue to something? Use case is just that I have a default value which is a long string and I don't want to directly paste it to the annotation parameter.

Comment: I don't understand your problem - how is putting a long value in a static field better than in the annotation parameter directly? In any case, if you must do that, you can use some other value like "null" as your defaul value, and then just access the value via the method I pasted above instead by field value. This will check if your value is equal to your predefined "default marker" value (in this case "null") and if so, will return the value of your static field instead

Comment: its increasing readability, one thing is that you will have giant string in the middle of method parameters declaration, the other thing if this string is extracted to some field and in `@Value` you just refer to that field.

Comment: oh right, my bad, i just glanced briefly at your question and haven't noticed this is in fact a method parameter. Check out @Dovmo's answer below