# How to inject property value using @Value into static fields

Tags: java, spring

I have one property file config.properties which is configured using spring property placeholder. This is how it's configured in my spring configuration file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/config.properties"/>
```

Now I need to set its value to **static** field using @Value annotation.

```
@Value("${outputfilepath}")
private static String outputPath;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You cannot. Create a singleton object instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make spring inject value into a static field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324372/how-to-make-spring-inject-value-into-a-static-field)

Comment: there is another approach to access variables of property files using @PropertySource please refer this link www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysoaurces-example/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only way is to use setter for this value

```
@Value("${value}")
public void setOutputPath(String outputPath) {
    AClass.outputPath = outputPath;
}
```

However you should avoid doing this. Spring is not designed for static injections. Thus you should use another way to set this field at start of your application, e.g. constructor.
Anyway @Value annotation uses springs PropertyPlaceholder which is still resolved after static fields are initialized. Thus you won't have any advantages for this construction

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to mimic a final aspect by using a static setter which will only set the value if it's currently null.

```
private static String outputPath;

public static String getOutputPath(){
   return outputPath;
}

private static setOutputPath( String op){
  if (outputPath == null) { 
      outputPath =  op;
  }
}

@Value("${outputfilepath}")
private setOutputFilePath(String outputFilePath){
  setOutputPath(outputFilePath);
}
```

Thanks to [Walfrat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5070577/walfrat) comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253694/spring-how-to-inject-a-value-to-static-field/7253751#comment68504224_7253751).