# how to initialize static data member using spring with out creating object of it

Tags: spring, spring-ioc

```
<bean name="staticHubInitializer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="very.public.api.StaticHub.setInstance"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myPrecious"/>
        </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

as i know spring ioc container create a bean MethodInvokingFactoryBean then it calls the setInstance() with parameter myPrecious just want  a clarification is there any way we can suggest that dont create a  object of it call directly ???

or is there any other way we can invoke the data member and assign the value to it directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make spring inject value into a static field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324372/how-to-make-spring-inject-value-into-a-static-field)

Comment: thanks for the link collind