# Reading Environment variable in SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables

I have an environment variable RESOURCES_FOLDER. Which i want to read in a class inside my Springboot application

```
@Value("${RESOURCES_FOLDER}")
private static String resourcesFolder;
```

When I try printing the value it gives null instead of printing the actual path in my environment variable. Can someone please help me with this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring does not allow injecting values into static fields. You have a few options to circumvent this restriction:

1. Create a non-static setter. This is not a particularly good approach, as `resourceFolder` will be shared by all instances of a class. Nevertheless, you should be able to achieve it by:

```
public class SomeClass {
    ...

    public static String resourcesFolder;

    @Value("${RESOURCES_FOLDER}")
    public void setResourcesFolder(String resourcesFolder) {
        this.resourcesFolder = resourcesFolder;
    }

    ...
}
```

2. Declare the field as non static. For this, ask yourself: do you really, really need the field to be static? Most of the time non-static field is good enough.
3. Create a separate [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) class, declare fields as private non-static, create getters/setters for it and inject the class wherever you need the variable. This is a very composable and testable approach, which I would recommend, especially if you have quite a few related properties.

Alternatively, please refer to the other similar questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253694/spring-how-to-inject-a-value-to-static-field), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324372/how-to-make-spring-inject-value-into-a-static-field/11324464).

Answer (score 0):

Add your environment variable name in the application.properties file by:

```
RESOURCE_FOLDER_PATH =${RESOURCES_FOLDER}
```

Here `RESOURCES_FOLDER` is the name of your environment variable.

Then access the environment variable in the java class by using `@value` annotation.

```
public class AccessEnvironmentVariable{

@Value("${RESOURCE_FOLDER_PATH}")
private String RESOURCE_FOLDER;

private void displayEnvironmentVariable(){
    System.out.println("Your environment variable Resource Folder: "+RESOURCE_FOLDER);
}
```

}